# How to suppress the file corrupt warning at CSVdownload?

Tags: java

I have a web page which links to an Excel 2007 worksheet. It is a upload details in .xlsx file and download in .csv file. When I click on the download link  and trying to open i get the usual dialog box to either open/save the Excel file. On clicking 'Open', I get the following warning message-

> The file you are trying to open, 'filename.csv' is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?

I developed this code in Java

```
private void downloadExcelSheet(HSSFWorkbook workbook, String sheetName){
    OutputStream out = null;
    try{

        ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        workbook.write(outByteStream);
        byte[] bytes = outByteStream.toByteArray(); //workbook.getBytes()
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();

        response.reset();
        String disHeader = "Attachment;Filename=\""+sheetName+".csv\"";
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);
        response.setContentType("text/csv");
        //response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+sheetName+".csv");
        //response.setContentType("text/csv");
        response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
        out = response.getOutputStream();
        out.write(bytes);
        out.flush();

    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try{
            if(out!=null){
                out.close();
            }
        }catch(IOException io){
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message kind of gives it away -- your workbook variable probably writes an XLSX, but you set the file extension to CSV. Change CSV to XLSX and you shouldn't get any error anymore...

Comment: If you _want_ it to be a CSV, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401755/csv-generation-possible-with-apache-poi

Comment: @Durgaprasad Why are you sending the wrong extension and content type?

Comment: I tried also .xlsx format it's not working.So i changed in .csv format.

Comment: Any Mistakes in my code.

Comment: The mistake is exactly what the error message says. You're using a .csv type but the file isn't in .csv format.

Comment: Now i want details download in text format means .txt file.How? It is possible.And where is it code available.